# Unrecognized Selector. Swift Unit Test for Swift extension of the ObjectiveC CocoaPod

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unit-testing

I have a project written in Swift.

I have an ObjectiveC cocoaPod and some Swift methods in extension for this objC class.

Now I am trying to write Unit Tests for those methods and it compiles fine but throws "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" when executes call of the method from extension.

What is interesting: If I change return value of the method in the extension to optional type - it works just fine.

EXAMPLE:

Pod file:

```
use_frameworks!

abstract_target 'App' do
    pod 'GoogleMaps', '2.1.1'

    target 'TestsBug'

    target 'TestsBugTests' do
        inherit! :complete
    end
end
```

Extension file:

```
import Foundation
import GoogleMaps

extension GMSPath {
    func func1() -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func func2() -> Int? {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Test:

```
func testExample() {
        let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: "abr~Frc`vOp@wwE")

        path?.func2()
        path?.func1()
    }
```

`func2` executes fine, on executing `func1` I'm getting `unrecognized selector sent to instance ...` error.

Comment: You're going to need to show some code and info on the selector that's being sent.

Comment: Added example, hope that helps.